# 1 hour Timer clock in python

Tags: python, loops, time

Basically I am trying to make a timer in python of 1 hour which will display it on terminal in this 
format HH:MM:SS

*for 3600 sec*

**Just it start it will show**

01:00:00

**after 1 sec passed**

00:59:59

**after a minute passed**

00:58:59

and so on

I tried a little code myself but can't figure out What i am doing wrong

```
import time as t
import os
time = 3600


os.system('cls')

while(time > 0):
    mint = int(time / 60)
    hrs = int((mint/60))
    sec = mint % 60
    print("time left --> ",hrs,":",mint,":",sec)
    time-=1
    t.sleep(1)
    os.system('cls')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `sec = mint % 60` to `sec = time % 60`
it also make more sense :)

Also consider using format:

`print("time left --> ",hrs,":",mint,":",sec)`

can be written as:

`print("time left --> {}:{}:{}".format(hrs,mint,sec))`

Comment: @Rajdeepsaha don't forget to mark it as the correct answer so it will help other people :)

Comment: I know its kinda late but will it work for 2 hours i.e 7200 sec or 3